# What's the best way to loop over single line with several separator?

Tags: bash, loops, shell, posix

I want to parse the output of `fio`, I have format them so it has a nice delimiter.

```
182.07 MB/s|182.55 MB/s|364.62 MB/s|45.5k|45.6k|91.2k#682.65 MB/s|686.24 MB/s|1.36 GB/s|10.7k|10.7k|21.4k#665.21 MB/s|700.56 MB/s|1.36 GB/s|1.3k|1.4k|2.7k#751.97 MB/s|802.05 MB/s|1.55 GB/s|0.7k|0.8k|1.5k
```

I want to process each string separated with `#` sign, currently this is what I do.

- Convert `#` to `\n` (newline)

  ```
  fio_result=$(printf %s "$fio_result" | tr '#' '\n')
  ```

  This will output the string like so.

  ```
  182.07 MB/s|182.55 MB/s|364.62 MB/s|45.5k|45.6k|91.2k
  682.65 MB/s|686.24 MB/s|1.36 GB/s|10.7k|10.7k|21.4k
  665.21 MB/s|700.56 MB/s|1.36 GB/s|1.3k|1.4k|2.7k
  751.97 MB/s|802.05 MB/s|1.55 GB/s|0.7k|0.8k|1.5k
  ```
- Only after that, loop through the variable `fio_result`.

  ```
  echo "$fio_result" | while IFS='|' read -r bla bla...
  ```

Does anyone have better idea how to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash you can do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

fio_result='182.07 MB/s|182.55 MB/s|364.62 MB/s|45.5k|45.6k|91.2k#682.65 MB/s|686.24 MB/s|1.36 GB/s|10.7k|10.7k|21.4k#665.21 MB/s|700.56 MB/s|1.36 GB/s|1.3k|1.4k|2.7k#751.97 MB/s|802.05 MB/s|1.55 GB/s|0.7k|0.8k|1.5k'

while IFS='|' read -d '#' -ra arr
do
    declare -p arr #=> shows what's inside 'arr'
done < <(
    printf '%s' "$fio_result"
)
```

But, if your need is to format/extract/compute something from `fio` output then you should switch to an other tool more fit for the job than bash.

Example with `awk`: calculate the average of the first two columns:

```sh
printf '%s' "$fio_result" |
awk -F'|' -v RS='#' '{print ($1+$2)/2}'
```